# I have a special responsive mobile store at m.MYdomain.com - how to make Magento detect mobile devices and forward the traffic to m.Mydomain.com?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, mobile

I've setup a subdomain = m.MYdomain.com with a Porto reponsive theme which is fully responsive (it seems to do a good job detecting the screen size and formatting the website accordingly). The reason I've setup m.myDOMAIN.com is so that I can include less text and way less products on the front page than I actually have on the front page of the desktop version. The point is - I don't need anything fancy (like detecting the actual size of the mobile device) but just differentiate:

**Is this a desktop the customer is using or a mobile device (phone, tablet) and if it detects a mobile device then - transfer the traffic to m.MYdomain.com**

*I'm sure there is a simple script I could just paste somewhere in the Magento Admin panel to make this happen?*

So to clarify once again:

- I've set up a new Magento store for our mobile site (under the same WEBSITE as the desktop version)
- I need to implement some logic to switch between the store views based on the client browser (maybe?) or detect if it's a computer or a mobile device they are using...

Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to Accomplish This:

You will want to utilize the "Miscellaneous Scripts" box for your non-mobile store (`System Configuration > Design > HTML Head`).

Then, use a script, similar to:

```
if (screen.width < 600 && document.cookie.indexOf('force_desktop') === -1) {
    window.location = "https://m.mydomain.com" + window.location.pathname;
}
```

#### What this Script Does:

This script will check two things: 1) is the width of the screen less than 600px? 2) is there a cookie that doesn't indicate forcing the desktop mode? If so, it will redirect to your sub-domain.

Keep in mind that while this works, it isn't ideal. This approach requires loading an entire page just to determine whether or not to redirect. For mobile users, this means a punishment of an extra page load (and their download times on average are slower).

#### Other Thoughts:

This answer is for strictly checking screen size (which is consisten with how responsive sites are built). If you are open to other approaches, I would recommend:

- Looking through the theme's CSS files to see if you can wrap text in a `</div>` tag to hide id, such as: `<div class="hidden-text"><p>A lot of text here.</p></div>`. This is the best approach in that your site is truly responsive.
- Using an `.htaccess` to [filter based on device type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess) I would not recommend this as it isn't foolproof.

#### Finally:

As a side note, you could make future site visits faster by:
* Setting a cookie in the same box, but on the mobile store: `document.cookie = "is_mobile_site=1;domain=mydomain.com"` (important to note that you need to specify the main domain name and not the sub-domain.
* Editing the `.htaccess` file to watch for `is_mobile_site` set and `force_desktop` is NOT set. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097662/htaccess-redirect-to-folder-if-cookie-is-missing.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for! Is there any way to bypass the desktop page loading in its entirety first? Because that's the whole point of getting a mobile site - instead of loading the 50 + products on the front page - I would like to load just 8 or so because I think loading 50 products on a mobile phone with a slow data connection is not good at all!

Comment: @Allysin, I just added the "Other Thoughts" area to my answer.

Comment: Joseph - I think I understand most everything you wrote except for the part to "wrap text in a -div tag to hide id....." Would this possibly hide some text AND some products as well? Anyways, I think I would like to hire you to do a small job I'm not able to do - would you be open to that? What is the best way to contact you? I clicked on the link to your website but I get an Error message (It does not resolve). Thank you.

Comment: @Allysin: Ouch. I see that it doesn't resolve. That is now fixed. You should be able to click it and contact me.