# m.MYDOMAIN.com versus www.m.MYDOMAIN.com for a special Magento mobile website

Tags: multistore, store-view, mobile, multidomain

Magento 1.9.1

I've setup a special **mobile** store/store front under a *subdomain* - **www.m.myDOMAIN.com** according to this tutorial:

http://www.wptaskforce.com/setting-magento-site-multiple-stores-subdomains/

I plan to put this code in the *Miscellaneous scripts* to make the system detect that a customer is connecting from a mobile device and forward the traffic to **www.m.myDOMAIN.com**:

[I have a special responsive mobile store at m.MYdomain.com - how to make Magento detect mobile devices and forward the traffic to m.Mydomain.com?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142434/i-have-a-special-responsive-mobile-store-at-m-mydomain-com-how-to-make-magento)

Now I need to figure out which actual sub-domain to go with:

1. **`www.m.MYDOMAIN.com`** actually loads the mobile store/store front the way I've set that up
2. When I punch in just **m.MYDOMAIN.com** - it loads the desktop version (same as www.MYDOMAIN.COM)

What to do here? *Is www.m.MYDOMAIN.com good enough* or *do I have to make the mobile site available on just m.MYDOMAIN.com and buy 2 SSL certificates one for each?*

Answer (score 0):

`m.mydomain.com` is a whole lot prettier than `www.m.mydomain.com`

Additionally, I hope that your actual domain will not be capitalized, like it is in your example. It should be all lowercase. Domains containing capital letters are not only unsightly but also unusual and  take away from credibility.